# create a table out of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a table whose columns are populated using existing tables.The table I want is

tbl_selection

```
Name of guide    No of trainees selected     No of trainees alotted
A                 2                            1
B                 1                            1
C                 1                            1
```

The column Name of guide is populated using tbl_registration , No of trainees selected using tbl_pencil and No of trainees alotted using allot_guide

tbl_registration

```
Guide_Name       PIN_NO         Designation
A                1              SC-C
B                2              SC-D
C                3              SC-E
```

tbl_pencil

```
TL_NO        Student_name   College   Guide_Name
TOO1            P           PQR         A
T002            Q           XYZ         A
T003            R           RST         B
T004            S           UVW         C
```

tbl_alotguide

```
TL_NO        Student_name          Guide_Name
T001          P                    A
TOO3          R                    B
TOO4          S                    C
```

Please help me find an appropriate query for the above

Comment: And what have you tryied to solve your problem?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I only have an idea that this will be making the use of count and join query ..But how to make it's use I dont know

Comment: Uptil now I have only been able to fill column1 ie Name of guide

Comment: The query I used for that is

Comment: CREATE TABLE tbl_selection(Name of guide VARCHAR(100),No of trainees_selected int,No of trainees_alotted int)
INSERT INTO tbl_selection (Name of guide)
SELECT Guide_Name
FROM registration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the second and third columns using the UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE tbl_selection 
SET No_of_trainees_selected = 
    (SELECT count(*) 
     FROM tbl_pencil 
     WHERE tbl_selection.name_of_guide = tbl_pencil.guide_name
     GROUP BY tbl_pencil.guide_name)
```

You can view UPDATE statement documentation in the next link:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer